# SSRS 2005 Export to Excel Alternating Row Color Issue

Tags: excel, reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

I have SSRS 2005 and my RDLs are formatted to have alternating row colors. When rendering the report in HTML or PDF the formatting is correct but when I try to export to Excel the alternating row colors do not show up. I tried using SSRS 2008 with the RDLs and somehow they work fine, but as much as I'd prefer using SSRS 2008 the client uses SSRS 2005 so upgrading to 2008 is out of the question. Can anyone point me to the right direction?

Thanks

Comment: SSRS 2005 was the 2.0 release of the product. Many, many improvements have come along since. If your client is doing much work with reports or SQL, upgrading will have a decent ROI.

Answer (score 0):

Although I think Jamie F is right and this is going to come down to an issue when exporting to Excel you may be able to work around this by highlighting the cells in another way.

Could you try going to *Text Box Properties* for any cell in a tablix control, then to *Fill* and under fill colour enter the following expression:

```
=iif(RowNumber(Nothing) Mod 2, "#eefafd", "White")
```

This will then highlight rows for that cell. If that works and you can export it to excel then you will need to apply this to the other cells as well.

Hopefully this gets you over the line and if you have any questions please let me know :)